# Intellij idea - spring project - don't see my files under the project

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

While working on my project in intellij idea using spring I've pressed some option unintentionally and now I don't see any of the classes under the project except for:
pom and iml.

Any one knows how to revert it?

(All the files are located at place - there weren't erased. Also the files that are still opened in idea are now marked with a red circle with the letter "J" in the middle)

Comment: You should find `Exclude` option in Module Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!!
Settings -> Maven - > Ignored Files
I had the pom file checked to ignore.